# Cross compiling "OpenSSL" Error

Tags: c, linux, openssl, cross-compiling

I'm using the include: < openssl/md5.h > in my c code. When I compile it with "gcc" compiler I don't have any errors, but when I compile it with cross compiler "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc" I have the following error:

```
/usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:56:33: fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory 
compilation terminated.
```

I think that this error is because I don't have the openssl libraries in the cross compiler folder "/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc".

Can anyone say me if is this the cause of the error? And how I can install the openssl libraries for cross compiler?

I'm starting in cross-compiling, and I don't have much knowledge about this.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you find solution? I too bumped this problem. I hope you found the answer as it is 9 months old. If you find the solution then answer it.

Comment: Same problem compiling under a container (Linux 4.13.13-6-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.13.13-42 (Fri, 9 Mar 2018 11:55:18 +0100) x86_64 GNU/Linux).

Comment: I just ran into this error after a lot of fiddling in order to cross-compile. As of 3.1.0, OpenSSL contains a file `include/openssl/opensslconf.h`. Somehow that file got deleted (which I found out when I opened git). Restore that file (`git reset --hard` if you use git, or re-extract the archive) and the error should be gone. No idea why the file got deleted in the first place, though.

Answer (score 16):

I know this question is a little old, but since I came to it with the same problem, I'm going to leave this here for future reference.

The solution I found was to manually compile OpenSSL with the installed cross-compiler and then manually install it to the cross-compilation libraries folder.

First, I installed the cross-compiler (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04). I installed both the C compiler and the C++ compiler. I also installed two cross-compiler toolchains, one with hard-floating point support (arm-linux-gnueabihf) and one without (arm-linux-gnueabi). Two directories are created (as noted on the question) `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi` and `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf`, where the cross-compiled libraries should be installed to.

```
sudo apt-get install {gcc,g++}-arm-linux-gnueabi{,hf}
```

Secondly, cloned the OpenSSL Git repository and checked out the version I was interested in (1.0.2):

```
git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl
git checkout OpenSSL_1_0_2       # or another version
```

Then, I configured the environment for cross-compilation and changed the installation directory (the prefix), and built the library following the instructions provided in the INSTALL file (and by forcing to use the specific cross-compilation toolchain):

```
export CROSS=arm-linux-gnueabi # or arm-linux-gnueabihf
export AR=${CROSS}-ar
export AS=${CROSS}-as
export CC=${CROSS}-gcc
export CXX=${CROSS}-g++
export LD=${CROSS}-ld

./Configure --prefix=/usr/${CROSS} os/compiler:${CC}
make
sudo make install
```

You can repeat the process and compile with both toolchains (`arm-linux-gnueabi` and `arm-linux-gnueabihf`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should consider using a chroot for this, as it will overwrite your system's openssl

Comment: Won't setting the prefix be enough?

Comment: have not tried it, but could be enough since configure should know where to install

Comment: This saved my day or should I say week. I had the exact issue where I needed to compile for an ARM and gcc linaro toolchain by default doesn't have the openssl lib.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, exactly the same error message (but I was compiling in 32 bits on a 64 bits machine). 
I solved this with installing another architecture:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev:i386
```

Comment: That does not work for arm64, the header is still put in a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries once built for a particular platform will be for a particular platform and can only be used on other platform only if its binary is compatible.

For cross-compilation, you may required binaries for different platforms too.

Regarding this error, it seems that you have not mentioned include path for OpenSSL header files.

Without libraries, you will get linker error, not compiler error.

In this case, compiler is somehow is not able to locate the header files. So, make sure that include path is provided.

Comment: I have mentioned the include in my c code. The include path that I have write is the following:'#include <openssl/md5.h>'. I think that I have to compile the openssl libraries to the cross compile? But how I can do it?

Comment: I think is a miss comentary

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

this also works for some oddball linux distros.